# How can I override Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus::createFromArray

Tags: 8

I have to form datelist field. If user select incorrect date, for example `1970-02-31`, displayed exception Exception:

> The array contains invalid values. in
>   Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus::createFromArray() (line 149 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Component/Datetime/DateTimePlus.php).

backtrace:

> 1. Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus::createFromArray() called
>      at [/var/www/drupal8/core/modules/datetime/datetime.module:802]
> 2. form_type_datelist_value() 2  call_user_func_array() called at
>      [/var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php:1542]
> 3. Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->handleInputElement() called at
>      [/var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php:1328]
> 4. Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm() called at
>      [/var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php:1390]
> 5. Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm() called at
>      [/var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php:1390]

I want override exception to return FALSE, and display to user warning about incorrect date.

How do I it?

Comment: Can't you just put a try catch statement around the calling code ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel Wehner suggests, this can easily be done by wrapping the *calling code* in a `try` - `catch` block. That's what it is for.